# JAX-WS vs. JAX-RPC

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, jax-rpc, websphere-7

I wrote 2 web services, one with Jax-WS and one with Jax-RPC.
They just return a String.

I stress-tested both with jMeter and, strangely, thereby Jax-RPC was a bit faster.

When do I really profit from Jax-WS in aspects of performance (response time, CPU time, heap)? How can I prove it?

Answer (score 38):

1. You didn't mention anything about the implementations you're using so it's hard to say anything about them :)
2. I don't know if your benchmark is representative of anything, I'm not sure it allows to make any valid conclusion.
3. JAX-WS is supposed to perform better in general than JAX-RPC, see [the already mentioned article](http://web.archive.org/web/20060813120808/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/high_performance/).
4. JAX-RPC is a dead standard that has been pruned in Java EE 6 (and might thus be removed from future versions). ***Reason for Pruning:** JAX-RPC was an early attempt at modeling SOAP web services as RPC calls. Web services have since grown out of being an RPC model. The much more robust, feature-rich and popular JAX-WS API effectively supercedes JAX-RPC.*

To summarize, I would definitely not base a new project on JAX-RPC.

Answer (score 4):

- **JAX-RPC 1.0:** Which works on `java.rmi.Remote` interface concept. And uses `RemoteException` i.e. all remote methods in a service endpoint interface (SEI) throw the standard `java.rmi.RemoteException`. **JAX-RPC 2.0** was renamed **JAX-WS 2.0**.
- **JAX-WS**: uses Annotations `@WebService`, `@SOAPBinding`, `@WebMethod`,  `@WebParam`, `@WebServiceClient` and so on.
- **Java:** JAX-RPC uses Java 1.4. JAX-WS uses Java 5.0.
- **SOAP:** JAX-RPC and JAX-WS support SOAP 1.1. JAX-WS also supports SOAP 1.2.
- **XML/HTTP** : The WSDL 1.1 specification defined an HTTP binding, which is a means by which you can send XML messages over HTTP without SOAP.JAX-RPC ignored the HTTP binding. JAX-WS adds support for it.
- **WS-I's(web services interoperability organization) Basic Profiles:** 
  JAX-RPC supports WS-I's Basic Profile (BP) version 1.0. JAX-WS supports BP 1.1.
- **Data Mapping Model**: JAX-RPC has its own data mapping model, JAX-WS's data mapping model is JAXB.