# JAX-RPC with Axis2

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, jax-rpc

I have been researching this like crazy, and have not been able to find an answer.

Is there any possible way to use JAX-RPC with Axis2?

I know Axis2 is compatible with JAX-WS, but I have not been able to find anything about

Comment: I recommend reading this previous answer about JAX-RPC and JAX-WS.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307516/jax-ws-vs-jax-rpc/3314458#3314458

Answer (score 2):

Axis2 has no support for JAX-RPC 1.1, it is instead using it's sucessor, JAX-WS 2.0.