# Creating new SOAP web service with JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

We are planning to create a new Web Service using RSA 7.5 and Websphere 7. But not able to understand whether to use JAX-RPC or JAX-WS.

I know that JAX-RPC is the older one and the newer one is JAX-WS. Is there some specific advantage of one above the another by which we can easily understand which one should be used?

I am used to JAX-RPC. JAX-WS is new to me, hence I would definitely love to go with something I am presently comfortable with. But I am worried if RPC will be deprecated in upcoming days may be in next 6 months which I am not at all sure.

Please suggest so that I can proceed with it and take the correct decision.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? Here's an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307516/jax-ws-vs-jax-rpc) on similar lines

Comment: Not an answer, but I can recommend you consider Spring WS

Comment: No. I did n't answered my question, its an open question to all and i posted what i am afraid of. Hence you may take it the either way if you are habituated of doing the same and giving some negetive marks. Thanks a buck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX-WS started as the next version of the JAX-RPC spec, but contained significant enough changes that it became a new spec.  If JAX-WS is available in your environment I would recommend using that instead of JAX-RPC.

My JAX-WS Example

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html