# Create a simple web services using JAX-RPC in Apache Axis

Tags: java, web-services, spring, axis, jax-rpc

I want to create a simple web services in Jax-RPC using Apache Axis.

I also want to implement spring nature to it.

I am new to Jax-RPC, could some share some references.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Apache Axis` and `JAX-RPC` are to independent frameworks for creating web services. Nobody could answer your question because there is no correct answer for it. What I can do is just give you some links to gets started with so that you could get better understanding what is JAX-RPC and Apache Axis.

See:

- [Web Services - Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/)
- [JAX-RPC](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/IntroWS5.html)

From all of your previous question related to this one, I am assuming that you need to support `rpc/encoded` WSDL style. Well, JAX-RPC and Axis will do that. Don't know how to do this via `JAX-RPC` but this is some hints how to do this with Axis and Spring:

Create two classes:

```
import org.apache.axis.EngineConfiguration;
import org.apache.axis.Handler;
import org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDProvider;
import org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService;

public class WSDDSpringProvider extends WSDDProvider {

    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "SPRING";
    public static final String PARAM_SPRING_BEAN_ID = "springBeanId";

    public String getName(){
        return "SPRING";
    }

    public Handler newProviderInstance(WSDDService service, EngineConfiguration registry)
        throws Exception {
        return new SpringProvider(service.getParameter("springBeanId"));
    }

}
```

And another:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider;
import org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class SpringProvider extends RPCProvider {

    private String springBeanId;

    public SpringProvider(String springBeanId) {
        this.springBeanId = springBeanId;
    }

    protected Object makeNewServiceObject(MessageContext msgContext, String clsName)
        throws Exception {
        Servlet servlet = (Servlet)msgContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLET);
        WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servlet.getServletConfig().getServletContext());
        return wac.getBean(springBeanId);
    }

    protected Object invokeMethod(MessageContext msgContext, Method method, Object obj, Object argValues[])
        throws Exception {
        Method proxyMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
        return proxyMethod.invoke(obj, argValues);
    }

}
```

Make them as a `.jar` file and put it into your classpath. These classes are handlers that your Axis web service's implementation class could be exposed as a Spring bean.

In `Axis WSDD` file configure `java:SPRING` provider for the web service which you want to expose as Spring bean. Define unique value for parameter `springBeanId`. For example (from WSDD file):

```
<ns:service name="TestService" provider="java:SPRING" use="literal">
   <ns:parameter name="springBeanId" value="webServiceImpl" />
   <!-- ... -->
</ns:service>
```

Define your web service implementation as Spring bean in `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, for example:

```
<bean id="webServiceImpl" class="your.pkg.WebServiceImpl">
</bean>
```

After these steps you are able to use your web service implementation class as common
Spring bean.

Comment: @User222 JAX-WS has superseded JAX-RPC. If you are implementing , consider JAX-WS. Also read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307516/jax-ws-vs-jax-rpc/3314458#3314458

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the documentation provided by spring:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html