# Regarding Jaxrpc jar

Tags: java, web-services

My application is using Jaxrpc 1.1 jar. I want to upgrade it to higher versions.

Higher versions for this jar was released but not available anywhere to download. I cannot use Jax ws. Please help, if I can get higher version Jaxrpc jar

My project is simple Java project. It's not maven. That's why I want to jar to place in my application

Comment: check at www.mavenrepository.com they usually contain all latest release

Comment: Already checked.. It's not available

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webservices-136604.html. checkout this link

Comment: When u will click this link jar will not be there.. Just check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't find a newer version of JAX-RPC is that JAX-RPC 2.0 was renamed JAX-WS 2.0 (Java API for XML Web Services) prior to its release.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML-based_RPC
- [JAX-WS vs. JAX-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307516/jax-ws-vs-jax-rpc/3314458#3314458)

---

For what it is worth, the source code for the JAX-RPC reference implementation is here:

- https://github.com/javaee/jax-rpc-ri

Version 1.1.3 is the last (and maybe only) version in the repository.  If you were really keen you could build your own JARs from the sources.   But there don't appear to have been any significant changes since 2006.

[image]

Comment: Yes I read that but Jax ws code is very different from Jaxrpc. It's not easy in application just to simply replace Jaxrpc with Jax ws. That's why I want it's higher version jar

Comment: Well ... there isn't one.   (Unless you want to write one yourself!)   If you want something newer, the JAX-WS is the way to go.  If don't want the effort of upgrading your code, stick with JAX-RPC.