# Has javax.xml.rpc been migrated to jakarta?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-8

We are migrating from javax packages to jakarta packages and hit a problem with `javax.xml.rpc.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext` as there doesn't seem to be an equivalent jakarta version.

There doesn't seem to be a replacement foe the `javax.xml.rpc` as far as we can see.

The problem we face is that the `SOAPMessageContext::getMessage()` method returns a `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` but we need a `jakarta.xml.soap.SOAPMessage`.

Perhaps the biggest problem is that this code has been in maintenance mode for over 10 years and the original authors of the code have long since left the organization.

We are in a big fog here and hope someone can point us in the right direction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. JAX-RPC was since Java EE 6 (dec 2009) deprecated in favor of JAX-WS.

Due to this deprecation status, JAX-RPC never made it into Jakarta EE. Just migrate to [JAX-WS](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/4.0/jakarta-xml-ws-spec-4.0).

#### See also:

- [JAX-WS vs. JAX-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307516/jax-ws-vs-jax-rpc/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my solution was:

- Update to the last jakarta.xml.soap-api
- Download the last jakarta.xml.rpc-api, but don't add to dependencies

Yes, there is a jakarta version of the rpc-api, but is done with the javax.xml.soap-api version and adds a dependency with javax.xml.soap classes.
To avoid this problem, you have to transform the "jakarta.xml.rpc-api" and add this tranformed jar to your dependencies:

https://github.com/eclipse/transformer

Maybe you need to add some dependencies brought previously by the original rpc-api jar.

And with this changes, all works fine for me with jdk17.